# Visual studio project without AssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I notice that some VS projects don't have AssemblyInfo in them. For example [Rx library](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) has the `Benchmarks.System.Reactive` project, which is the console project and doesn't have AssemblyInfo:

[image]

But if i add the new console project to this assembly, this newly created project will have the AssemblyInfo:

[image]
How can i create this type of project without assemblyinfo?

Comment: just delete them. msbuild can configure that now.

Comment: What do you mean by delete them? If you meant deleting AssemblyFile from project directory then i tried to do so, bu the Assembly Info is still there, the only difference is that all the fields are blank

Comment: The .net standard project template (.NET Sdk) can read these settings from the project file (or assembly info). You can use those templates for a nornal .NET project but *it's not the default* so you have to do some tweaking. Create a new project and then Google "upgrade csproj to new format", one of the first few links shows you how

Comment: It only *seems* like it is necessary to have an AssemblyInfo.cs source file, many project templates create one.  This is not accurate, neither msbuild nor the CLR need these attributes.  Only [AssemblyVersion] is truly important, but matters only for a library project and when it is missing then it simply becomes 0.0.0.0.  For a benchmark they only add unnecessary noise, so the programmer opted to delete the file from the project.  So can you, right-click > Delete.